# Can I use an iPod nano 8g as a flash drive for windows, and still use it to play the music I paste in that drive?

Tags: itunes, music, ipod, ipod-nano

I know I can use an iPod nano as a flash drive by connecting the iPod to the computer and selecting the iTunes option "Enable disk use".
(as stated here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3091809?tstart=0)

My question is, after doing that, if I paste an mp3 song from the windows folder explorer (I mean, without using iTunes).
Will I be able to play that song on the go with the iPod?

My goal is to make an iPod nano behave just like any other mp4 player, play any song I copy from my PC without using iTunes, and also use it to take other files with me.

Answer (score 2):

## No.

### Apple does not want you to manage your own music.

#### Apple specifically engineered their products to prevent you from easily dragging and dropping files for quick portable usage.

**Reasoning behind this is to encourages more sales from iTunes by forcing users to only use iTunes to manage music.**

To quote Apple,

> When you use your iPod as a hard disk, you can't see the media iTunes
> copies to your iPod in the Finder or My Computer. This is normal.
> Using the Finder or My Computer, you can't copy these media files from
> your iPod back to iTunes or to any other computer. **The synchronization**
> **between your iPod and your computer is one way: from iTunes to iPod.**

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201567

#### *A warning: Keep your backups handy because once your music is in the iPod it's difficult or impossible to get back*